# What's the fastest way to generate k-set from a list of integers?

Tags: algorithm, set, combinatorics

I want to generate all k-set(k=2 to 4) which always contains the first element 0 from an ordered list of integer {0, 1, 2, 3}:
[{0,1},{0,2},{0,3},{0,1,2}, {0,1,3},{0,2,3},{0,1,2,3}].

Currently, my way is 
* m=2: [{0,1},{0,2},{0,3}],
* m=3: derived from m=2 by only adding element in the list which is bigger than the biggest element of (m-1) set: [{0,1,2}, {0,1,3}, {0,2,3}}], for example, here [2,3] are bigger than the 1 which is the biggest integer the set {0,1}, so they are added and I got 2 more sets {0,1,2},{0,1,3}.

It works but when n is big it's not fast enough.

I wonder what's the faster way to generate these sets.

Comment: This is equivalent to generating the *k - 1* set from the set not containing 0. For *k = 4*, the running time is cubic. This won't be fast for large *n* using *any* algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother about 0 - add it in the end

Make simple cycle with counter from `1` to `2^(k-1) - 1` (here for 1..7)

Every counter value corresponds to one set of elements - consider that if j-th bit is 1, then j presents in set.

For example, 5 = binary 101 corresponds to set {1,3} (first and third bits are ones)

Comment: Good idea. The only thing is that the elements of k-set is scattered.

Comment: What does it mean here - scattered? If set is like {1,7,288,999}, then you can put it in array and use array indexes.

Comment: What I meant is : To get a 1-set of list [1,2,3], you get elements from 1,2,4.  But yes it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If `k` is fixed to be 2-4 but `n` varies, there is no reason to avoid the use of nested loops. Here is a Python generator which will efficiently iterate over all such subsets. It makes heavy use of the built-in function `enumerate()` but the core idea is easily implemented in any language:

```
def enumerator(nums):
    #enumerates the k-element subsets of set nums
    #which have between 2 and 4 elements, including
    #the smallest element:

    pool = sorted(list(nums)) #make a sorted copy
    a = pool[0]
    pool = pool[1:] #remaining items
    n = len(pool)

    #first the 2-element subsets:

    for b in pool:
        yield {a,b}

    #3-element subsets:
    for i,b in enumerate(pool[:n-1]):
        for c in pool[i+1:]:
            yield {a,b,c}

    #4-element subsets:

    for i,b in enumerate(pool[:n-2]):
        for j,c in enumerate(pool[i+1:n-1]):
            for d in pool[j+2:]:  #enumerate() starts with 0 - so bump up 2
                yield {a,b,c,d}
```

For example:

```
>>> for s in enumerator({0,1,2,3}): print(s)

{0, 1}
{0, 2}
{0, 3}
{0, 1, 2}
{0, 1, 3}
{0, 2, 3}
{0, 1, 2, 3}
```

If `k` isn't fixed to this range, use one of the algorithms described in the Wikipedia article on [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Enumerating_k-combinations).